# Expand sparse table with self outer join on distinct values

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, join, null

I have this:

```
g1       | g2        | x
---------+-----------+-----
New York | Monday    | 210
New York | Tuesday   | 258
Chicago  | Monday    | 30
Chicago  | Wednesday | 25
LA       | Thursday  | 40
```

But I want this:

```
g1       | g2        | x
---------+-----------+-----
New York | Monday    | 210
New York | Tuesday   | 258
New York | Wednesday | NULL
New York | Thursday  | NULL
Chicago  | Monday    | 30
Chicago  | Tuesday   | NULL
Chicago  | Wednesday | 25
Chicago  | Thursday  | NULL
LA       | Monday    | NULL
LA       | Tuesday   | NULL
LA       | Wednesday | NULL
LA       | Thursday  | 40
```

In other words, I want a record for every combination of `DISTINCT g1` and `DISTINCT g2`. I should note that `g1` and `g2` are arbitrary groupings (not always location- or date-related). How do I fill in the table with these `NULL` values based on the cross product?

Comment: Do you really want that, or would you like `g2` to just be every single date in a specific date range? Just asking for completeness.

Comment: Yes, I really want the cross product. I'm looking for a general approach where `g1` and `g2` are user-defined groupings (not always days of the week or dates).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is any more straightforward, but I would change the syntax to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of the `(+)`

```
select t1.g1,
  t1.g2,
  t2.x
from
(
  select distinct t1.g1, t2.g2
  from yourtable t1
  cross join (select g2 from yourtable) t2
) t1
left join yourtable t2
  on t1.g1 = t2.g1
  and t1.g2 = t2.g2
order by t1.g1, t1.g2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/862f8/11)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original table is `d`, this seems to work, but is there a more efficient or straightforward way?

```
SELECT cp.g1,
  cp.g2,
  d.x
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT d1.g1, d2.g2 FROM d d1, d d2
  ) cp,
  d
WHERE d.g1 (+) = cp.g1
AND d.g2 (+)   = cp.g2
```